# Loading different assembly versions using reflection

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I am trying to compare the output of different library versions, and to achieve that I'm trying to load different versions of the library through reflection.

I've put the different version dll's in a subfolder of the project. They are being copied and in the deployment folder.

The code I use to load is as follows:

```
var uri = new UriBuilder(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path));
string path = Path.Combine(dir, $@"mylibrary\{version}.dll");
Assembly library = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
```

However, the strange thing is that **always the version of the library gets loaded which was loaded first**. E.g. load 2.0 first then try to load 1.0 means 2.0 gets loaded again, and loading 1.0 first means 1.0 gets loaded again when I load 2.0 after.

When I try to load another version and look at the debugging information `path` is correct, but the `CodeBase` of the assembly is the newer library .dll.

Any idea what is causing this?

P.S. I've tried statically binding with `extern alias`, but that fails because the libraries are unsigned so I get an error that assemblies with the same name cannot be loaded side by side unless they are signed.

Comment: Only one version of same assembly can be loaded per **AppDomain**, it's not like *plain* DLLs where path matters. You have to load each version in a different AppDomain (or use one you unload time after time).